# Continuous dense restriction makes the whole map an continusou mapping?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a map. Let $U$ be an open and dense subset of  $X$ such that the restriction of $f$, $f_{|U}:U \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.
Is then the whole mapping $f$ continuous?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Put $X=Y=\Bbb R$ endowed with the usual topology, $U=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, and $f(x)=x$, if  $x\ne 0$ and $f(x)=1$.

Comment: the function f(x)=1/x is continuous on the open dense set R\{0} but it cannot be extended to a continuous function on R. Even if f(x) is bounded for example f(x)=sin(1/x),x not zero.